# iOS custom cells not working

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, custom-cell

I am new to iOS app development. I am trying to make a table view with custom cells but i can't achieve it. The code is crashing without any error message and it says 
`Thread1: Program received signal Sigbart`. Please help me with it.

SimpleTableCell.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SimpleTableCell : UITableViewCell
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *nameLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *prepTimeLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *thumbNailImageView;

@end
```

SimpleTableCell.m

```
 #import "SimpleTableCell.h"

@implementation SimpleTableCell
@synthesize nameLabel;
@synthesize prepTimeLabel;
@synthesize thumbNailImageView;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

@end
```

SimpleTableViewController.h

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SimpleTableViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *table;

@end
```

SimpleTableViewController.m

```
#import "SimpleTableViewController.h"
#import "SimpleTableCell.h"
@implementation SimpleTableViewController
{
    NSArray *tableData;
    NSArray *thumbnails;
    NSArray *prepTime;
}
@synthesize table;
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    tableData = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Egg Benedict", @"Mushroom Risotto", @"Full Breakfast", @"Hamburger", @"Ham and Egg Sandwich", @"Creme Brelee", @"White Chocolate Donut", @"Starbucks Coffee", @"Vegetable Curry", @"Instant Noodle with Egg", @"Noodle with BBQ Pork", @"Japanese Noodle with Pork", @"Green Tea", @"Thai Shrimp Cake", @"Angry Birds Cake", @"Ham and Cheese Panini", nil];

    thumbnails = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"egg_benedict.jpg", @"mushroom_risotto.jpg", @"full_breakfast.jpg", @"hamburger.jpg", @"ham_and_egg_sandwich.jpg", @"creme_brelee.jpg", @"white_chocolate_donut.jpg", @"starbucks_coffee.jpg", @"vegetable_curry.jpg", @"instant_noodle_with_egg.jpg", @"noodle_with_bbq_pork.jpg", @"japanese_noodle_with_pork.jpg", @"green_tea.jpg", @"thai_shrimp_cake.jpg", @"angry_birds_cake.jpg", @"ham_and_cheese_panini.jpg", nil];

    prepTime = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"30 min", @"30 min", @"20 min", @"30 min", @"10 min", @"1 hour", @"45 min", @"5 min", @"30 min", @"8 min", @"20 min", @"20 min", @"5 min", @"1.5 hour", @"4 hours", @"10 min", nil];

}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [tableData count];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";

    SimpleTableCell *cell = (SimpleTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SimpleTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    } 

    cell.nameLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.thumbNailImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[thumbnails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    cell.prepTimeLabel.text = [prepTime objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [self setTable:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];

}

@end
```

Please help. Thanks

Comment: Check your Iboutlet are properly connected & it may be problem due to array index.

Comment: Check the tableData.count in numberOfRowsInSection function. Check if it's not 0.

Comment: @Vishal In SimpleTableCell, You use (strong, nonatomic) property for custom cell and check your IBOutlet connection.

Comment: Thanks for replying . I have joined the iboutlets in nib. I even tried changing te property from weak to strong . Still no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proble lies in the *cellForRowAtIndexPath* section. In which you define a cell as first object nib array. But it may not be a **UITableViewCell** class. So you have to check whether it is a **UITableViewCell** class object. Try this

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";

    SimpleTableCell *cell = (SimpleTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SimpleTableCell" owner:nil options:nil];
        for (id eachObject in nib) {
            if ([eachObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
                cell = eachObject;
                break;
            }
        }
    } 

    cell.nameLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.thumbNailImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[thumbnails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    cell.prepTimeLabel.text = [prepTime objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: I tried it , still no luck . Actually i put a break point on viewdidload method. The code is crashing even before that method

Answer (score 1):

Custom cells need to be registered for reuse before calling dequeue....]

You can do this in the viewDidLoad

```
[self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CustomCell"];
```

Comment: There is a registerNib too.

Answer (score 0):

You should double check all connections in Interface Builder. It look likes you have a error in connection between your cell or controller to xib files

Comment: I have conected IBoutlets in TableCell xib. In TableViewCOntroller i am using TableviewCOntroller and mapped its table view . Is anything else needs to be done beside what i did??

Comment: I think your SimpleTableViewController class is inherited from UIViewController, not from UITableViewController. Check your class of File's Owner in xib file